# GWD Mobile Animation Doesn't Stop

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, css-animations

I made an animation with Google Web Designer. This animation working in desktop but in mobile doesn't work. Actually it works but when i try to stop animation doesn't stop. gwd.timeline.stop not supported in mobile browser.

When i trying the following codes no-animtion class added to page1 but the animation doesn't stop. How can i solve that problem?

```
.no-animation{
    -webkit-animation: none !important;
    -moz-animation: none !important;
    animation: none !important;
}


gwd.anim = function(event) {
  $('#page1').addClass("no-animation");
  console.log("stoped");
};
```

Thanks,

Hakan

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GWD, then you con use timeline animations instead of CSS animation.

Here is the documentation related to how to build time line animation

- [Add event markers and event labels to the timeline](https://support.google.com/webdesigner/answer/4597391?hl=en)
- [Create animations in Advanced mode](https://support.google.com/webdesigner/answer/6065570?hl=en)
- [Looping animations](https://support.google.com/webdesigner/answer/6307672?hl=en)

Let me know if you need more information